# HTML bootstrap textbox alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a registration page with two labels and two text boxes. The first text box I coded as date-time picker with bootstrap, along with text box calendar glyphicon is there and next is a simple text box.

My problem is both are not aligned properly - all other text boxes are aligned but not that date-time picker text box. I think that is because of the glyphicon.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="dob" class="control-label col-xs-4">Date Of Join:
  </label>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="col-lg-8 input-group date form_date2" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
      <input type="text" class="form-control span2" name="doj" id="date">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name" class="control-label col-xs-4">Education :
  </label>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="col-lg-8">

      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacherName" id="education" placeholder="Enter highest degree">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
```

Sorry I cant upload the image of that. Please can any one help in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried out the same code. Here's what I got. There were no alignment issues.
[image]

I would suggest go through the styles in developer tools (press F12 in your browser and try to find out if there are any styles screwing things up)

**EDIT:**

Try this.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="date">Date Of:</label>

    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="col-lg-8 input-group date form_date2" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
            <input type="text" class="form-control span2" name="doj" id="date">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="education">Education:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="col-lg-8  input-group ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacherName"
                id="education" placeholder="Enter highest degree">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe he is using a different browser? In which browser have you tested this @Dirnthelord?

Comment: Chrome. Firefox is also renders it well. Didn't check in IE tho.

Comment: and here also slight change in text boxes . I want date text box is to be same of edu text box